# Weird output with class getter function C++

Tags: c++, oop, getter-setter

So I have this piece of code for a darts game, in my header file:

```
    class Player
    {
    private:
        string playerName;
        int bullAccuracy;
        int outerAccuracy;
        int singleAccuracy;
    public:

        //getters
        string& getName();
        int& getBullAccuracy();
        int& getSingleAccuracy();

        //setters
        void setName(string& name);
        void setBullAccuracy(int& bull_accuracy);
        void setSingleAccuracy(int& single_accuracy);
    };
```

And then the correspondent getter and setter functions in the .cpp file look like this:

```
    //getters
    string& Player::getName()
    {
        return playerName;
    }
    unsigned int& Player::getScore()
    {
        return playerScore;
    }
    int& Player::getBullAccuracy()
    {
        return bullAccuracy;
    }
    int& Player::getSingleAccuracy() 
    {
        return singleAccuracy;
    }

//setters
void Player::setName(string& name)
{
    playerName = name;
}
void Player::setBullAccuracy(int& bull_accuracy)
{
    bullAccuracy = bull_accuracy;
}
void Player::setSingleAccuracy(int& single_accuracy)
{
    singleAccuracy = single_accuracy;
}
```

All of this very simple and basic getter/setter code for a class data memebers, right?

In the main() function though, I set the names for my players, their various accuracies, and then display them throught the getters. All of these are done using vectors of objects and iterators, like this:

```
vector<Player> player(2);
vector<Player>::iterator modIter;
int bAccuracy, sAccuracy;
string playerName;
cout << "Input the name of the players: " << endl;
for (modIter = player.begin(); modIter != player.end(); modIter++)
{
    cin >> playerName;
    modIter->setName(playerName);
}
cout << "\nSet the players' bull accuracy:" << endl;
for (modIter = player.begin(); modIter != player.end(); modIter++)
{
    cout << modIter->getName() << ": ";
    cin >> bAccuracy;
    modIter->setBullAccuracy(bAccuracy);
}
cout << "\nSet the players' single hit accuracy: " << endl;
for (modIter = player.begin(); modIter != player.end(); modIter++)
{
    cout << modIter->getName() << ": ";
    cin >> sAccuracy;
    modIter->setBullAccuracy(sAccuracy);
}
//display values to check program working well so far
for (modIter = player.begin(); modIter != player.end(); modIter++)
{
    cout << modIter->getBullAccuracy() << endl;
    cout << modIter->getOuterAccuracy() << endl;
    cout << modIter->getSingleAccuracy() << endl;
}
```

And after running the code, and typing in input "Joe" and "Sid" for the names, 71 and 73 respectively for bull accuracy, and then 80 for both players for the single hit accuracy, this is what my console outputs:

Input the name of the players:

Joe

Sid

Set the player's bull accuracy:

Joe: 71

Sid: 73 //this means that at least the names were set correctly

Set the player's single hit accuracy:

Joe: 80

Sid: 80

//and here is the weird output

80 //this is supposed to be 71

-842150451 //and this 80

80 //here the 73

-842150451 //and here again 80

So what exactly happened because this is really basic and familiar use of getters and setters, and I have no idea how to debug this by myself since I don't see the issue. Is there something in my code that I can't see that's altering the results?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: accept the below answer. It will help get some points for both of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you prompt for single accuracy, you're still calling `setBullAccuracy` method, not `setSingleAccuracy`. You also didn't initialize your member variables which is why printing out `singleAccuracy` is giving you garbage.

Comment: My goodness, thank you. I did not see that. One quick question, out of curiosity, since you mentioned initializing. If my code were correct from the beginning, why should I initialize the member variables? Wouldn't they get the value that I input and count that as initialization?

Comment: If you never set a class member or local variable it will be uninitialized which means it will contain random garbage. The compiler will not set it to 0 unless you tell it. ***Wouldn't they get the value that I input and count that as initialization?*** Yes if you used the correct function `singleAccuracy` would have been initialized. Although I would have provided a constructor and initialized all of the integers to 0 or some  other sentinel value.

Comment: Pretty much what @drescherjm said. It's considered good practice to explicitly initialize all your member variables. For example, if you had initialized your member variables to 0, your output would be `80 0 80 0`, and I find that more helpful when trying to debug: it's basically saying "Hey, you haven't assigned any values to `singleAccuracy`, which is why it still has the default value of 0", versus being confused over why garbage is being outputted.